# OpenCV imread() is not working

Tags: opencv, imread

I have this simple code to open an image but it shows blank image in the "Video" window. I have checked release and debug lib's to make sure. It is in release mode and the lib is release lib. The picture is there, and I also tried full path for the image but still doesn't work. Also tried different image formats: jpg, png, bmp. It is OpenCV 3.4.1 release, and VS 2017 (also tried 2015).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    namedWindow("Video");

    Mat frame1 = imread("Penguins.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR ); 

    imshow("Video", frame1);

    system("Pause");

    return 0;


}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `waitKey()` function after `imshow()`. You can pass in a delay parameter to show the image for a certain time (in milliseconds).

**Example:**

```
#--- It will display the image for 30 ms 
waitKey(30);

#--- It will display the image until a key is pressed
waitKey();
```

Check [THIS PAGE](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) for more.

There is also a demo example shown [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)